# How to prevent people from leaving comments on a page that I administer?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I tried going into the permissions and unchecking the boxes shown below:

[image: configuration details]

but people can still post comments.

Do I need to specify this somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Those two check boxes are for people that either like or have not yet liked the page.

When checked:

- People that **`don't like`** the page ***`can`*** post
- People that **`do like`** the page ***`can`*** post

When unchecked:

- People that **`don't like`** the page ***`cannot`*** post
- People that **`do like`** the page ***`can`*** post

However, you can change the default visibility of posts by others on your page, but you cannot affect visibility of comments by others on the things you post:

within the same settings page:

[image: Facebook page settings moderation and others post visibility]

- Uncheck "Show the box..."
- Choose "Hidden from page" in the "Default visibility..." select.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that people who have liked the page cannot post?

Comment: Not anymore. It used to be possible, but Facebook has chosen to be more open now. However you can now moderate your posts [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=356113237741414). Updating answer to account for moderation which could let you accomplish what you asked.